# endpoint_failure (context canceled) resulting in duplicate call to REST Endpoint

Tags: java, spring-boot, resttemplate

Am invoking an REST endpoint from another service using restTemplate.exchange.

The endpoint that receives the request  invokes DB and fetches around 1.5 mil records and stores them in another DB.

Now am getting below x_cf_routererror:"endpoint_failure (context canceled)" after invoking the DB. I get this error in about 120+ seconds and process continues as is.

After this error I see another call being made the same endpoint and this is resulting duplicates in target DB.

Not sure why this is happening, I do not have any retry mechanism in place and the restTempalte timeout is set to 300 at client service that invokes.

Has someone faced this issue? whats causing this endpoint_failure (context canceled) and duplicate invocation of endpoint.

Appreciate your help in this.

Log snippet:

```
2022-05-12T08:57:18.840-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2022-05-12 12:57:18.840 INFO 28 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] 
Controller1 : Request received to load all timecard information::RequestedTime=12:57:18.840


2022-05-12T08:59:21.530-04:00 [RTR/17] [OUT]  - [2022-05-12T12:57:18.829182975Z] "GET  HTTP/1.1" 499 0 22 "-" "Java/1.8.0_332" "" "1" x_forwarded_for:"" x_forwarded_proto:"https" vcap_request_id:"" response_time:122.701301 gorouter_time:0.000164 app_id:"" app_index:"0" instance_id:"" x_cf_routererror:"endpoint_failure (context canceled)" x_b3_traceid:"" x_b3_spanid:"" x_b3_parentspanid:"-" b3:"599552bb012c2adc60adef7187a865e7-60adef7187a865e7"

**Below is the duplicate call**

2022-05-12T08:59:21.777-04:00 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] [OUT] 2022-05-12 12:59:21.777 INFO 28 --- [nio-8080-exec-2]
Controller1 : Request received to load all timecard information::RequestedTime=12:59:21.777
```

Thanks,
S

Answer (score 1):

Error 499 usually mean that call is taking too much of time and client closed the connection. It has been noticed many times when your app is not able to get a response within specific time (usually 2min time limit set). You might need to see if there is any DB issue or something else that delaying the expected response.

Answer (score 0):

The error 499 (or 502) is returned by PCF gorouter, instead of your web app [APP/PROC/WEB/0].

PCF gorouter will retry with same HTTP request for particular error cases.
For more details please refer to: https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/adminguide/troubleshooting-router-error-responses.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).